# Remotely discover if Windows is OEM or Volume license

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, license, oem, volume-license

Previous tech did not document installs and now we are left with the question: Which machines have OEM or Volume license on them? Many of the machines have OEM keys available but were installed incorrectly with the Volume keys. I would like to automate this process as we will need to be going through 100 computers with half of those from a remote location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also do this in a batch script:

`systeminfo /S %computername% | findstr "Product ID:"`

OEM installs will have the word "OEM" in the returned Product ID. With the `/S` flag, you could check a remote system as well, just replace `%computername%` with the hostname. It would be easy to provide a list of computers, and run it through a FOR loop to check and save the values to a file.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for [Spiceworks IT Desktop 1.7](http://www.spiceworks.com/1.7/), Your network management tool for everything IT!

```
Extended Software Compliance Capabilities

Collect license key info, product ID and product key for Microsoft OS and Office products, 
allowing you to ensure you stay compliant with your license allotment (future releases 
will allow you to enter third party keys). In the 'inventory' tab, just click on the 
'software' category, pick a MS product, then click on 'Installed On'.
```